# Removing rows that contain NA values also removes all rows that contain values

Tags: r, na, missing-data

all rows of United States got removed here.
[image: data_after_na.omit]
real data:
[image: data]

Hi, having an issue where I want to omit rows that contain NA values, but once I use `na.omit()` the entire dataframe is gone. I think I am doing something wrong. I want to keep the values that exist within the Carbon_Footprint_percapita column, and delete the rows that show NA values.

my code is:

```
    us_df <- country_data %>%
      filter(country == "United States")
    
    us_df <- us_df %>%
      na.omit()
```

any help is appreciated. thank you!

I tried to use `complete.cases()` and `drop_na()` but one returns a list, and the other does the same as the above mentioned code. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have `NA` values in other columns.  So, `tidyr::drop_na` will work fine in your case.  You just need to pass column name in the code.

See on this dummy data.  First code works as desired while second one doesn't.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  data1 = c(NA, 11:13, NA),
  data2 = c(100, NA, NA, NA, 115)
)

df
#>   id data1 data2
#> 1  1    NA   100
#> 2  2    11    NA
#> 3  3    12    NA
#> 4  4    13    NA
#> 5  5    NA   115

df %>% 
  drop_na(data1)
#>   id data1 data2
#> 1  2    11    NA
#> 2  3    12    NA
#> 3  4    13    NA

df %>% 
  na.omit(data1)
#> [1] id    data1 data2
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I figured it out later on. I used drop_na and na.omit but neither worked for my instance. I resorted to filter(!is.na()) and that worked for me. Thanks for your help!